# I can't update after installing 5.1.4

Tags: updates

I'm still learning about linux, so I don't know how to fix it, but I'll explain what happened
I just did dual boot, put / on ssd and /home on hdd ...
I used ISO 5.1.4 Hera
When I first opened the store:
[image]

Comment: you mean by "first opened the store" that you opened the app center and all of sudden the terminal opened? (that black window you pasted a screenshot of it)

Comment: I just put an image after running sudo apt-get update to be able to show it more completely, the app center warning was more simplified, but the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a terminal:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
```

Update will take some time because it's re-downloading all the files.